# How to pass a bigger .csv files to amazon sagemaker for predictions using batch transform jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker

I created a custom model and deployed it on sagemaker. I am invoking the endpoint using batch transform jobs. It works if the input file is small, i.e, number of rows in the csv file is less. If I upload a file with around 200000 rows, I am getting this error in the cloudwatch logs.

```
2018-11-21 09:11:52.666476: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:113]
Allocation of 2878368000 exceeds 10% of system memory.
2018-11-21 09:11:53.166493: W external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/framework/allocator.cc:113] 
Allocation of 2878368000 exceeds 10% of system memory.
[2018-11-21 09:12:02,544] ERROR in serving: <_Rendezvous of RPC that 
terminated with:
#011status = StatusCode.DEADLINE_EXCEEDED
#011details = "Deadline Exceeded"
#011debug_error_string = "
{
"created": "@1542791522.543282048",
"description": "Error received from peer",
"file": "src/core/lib/surface/call.cc",
"file_line": 1017,
"grpc_message": "Deadline Exceeded",
"grpc_status": 4
}
"
```

Any ideas what might be going wrong. This is the transform function which I am using to create the transform job.

```
transformer =sagemaker.transformer.Transformer(
base_transform_job_name='Batch-Transform',
model_name='sagemaker-tensorflow-2018-11-21-07-58-15-887',
instance_count=1,
instance_type='ml.m4.xlarge',
output_path='s3://2-n2m-sagemaker-json-output/out_files/'

)
input_location = 's3://1-n2m-n2g-csv-input/smal_sagemaker_sample.csv'
transformer.transform(input_location, content_type='text/csv', split_type='Line')
```

The .csv file contains 2 columns for first and last name of customer, which I am then preprocessing it in the sagemaker itself using input_fn().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error looks to be coming from a GRPC client closing the connection before the server is able to respond. (There looks to be an existing feature request for the sagemaker tensorflow container on https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container/issues/46 to make this timeout configurable)

You could try out a few things with the sagemaker Transformer to limit the size of each individual request so that it fits within the timeout:

- Set a `max_payload` to a smaller value, say 2-3 MB ([the default is 6 MB](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/API_CreateTransformJob.html#SageMaker-CreateTransformJob-request-MaxPayloadInMB))
- If your instance metrics indicate it has compute / memory resources to spare, try `max_concurrent_transforms` > 1 to make use of multiple workers
- Split up your csv file into multiple input files. With a bigger dataset, you could also increase the instance count to fan out processing

Answer (score 1):

A change was made and merged in to allow users to configure the timeout through an environment variable, SAGEMAKER_TFS_GRPC_REQUEST_TIMEOUT.

- https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container/pull/135
- https://github.com/aws/sagemaker-tensorflow-container/blob/master/src/tf_container/proxy_client.py#L30